# How to merge and display data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, optimization

Hopefully this is not too subjective, but:

I have a problem where I need to query data from four different tables based on an ID. This data has similar but not identical fields that need to be displayed for each table. Essentially, if I have tables A, B, C, and D, then for an id N, I might need to display rows in the following order:

```
A1

B1
B2
B3

C1

D1
D2
D3
D4
```

However, since some of B and D requires that I join to many tables, and I have tens of thousands of records, I don't want to be sending four complex queries for every id. I was of pre-building my data - creating a temporary table that houses each of the final A,B,C,D data and then querying directly by ID to those rows. Is there a faster way? I've thought of using a UNION but my rows don't all have the same kinds of columns (for rows of type A I might need to display a date, while rows of type C will have an integer day offset, for example).

My current approach:

```
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $a = "SELECT * FROM a JOIN xyz (...) WHERE id = ?";
    $b = "SELECT * FROM b JOIN xyz (...) WHERE id = ?";
    $c = "SELECT * FROM c JOIN xyz (...) WHERE id = ?";
    $d = "SELECT * FROM d JOIN xyz (...) WHERE id = ?";

    print query($a, $id)->fetch();
    print query($b, $id)->fetchAll();
    print query($c, $id)->fetch();
    print query($d, $id)->fetchAll();
}
```

Or something like that

Comment: Show your approach in code. Also, which DBMS do you use? I doubt you have issue with `mysql` `sql-server` and `postgresql` while solving this problem

Comment: fixed. I use postgres, but the particular DBMS doesn't matter so much as the approach.

Comment: You could look into `FULL JOIN` if I understand correctly, or go with `UNION` and generate `NULL` values for queries where you don't have some columns

Comment: If the rows have different columns, then you either need four queries or to put placeholders in each subquery for the "extra" columns.

Comment: In the realm of the temp table idea, have you considered using a View? That way you can abstract the query logic from your display queries so each data pull isn't massively complicated. With a view you also maintain a small virtual datamart of the info you wish to see which may be helpful with future data pulls.

Comment: I'll think about using a view - my main concern is that I'm sending like 40,000 complex queries for 10,000 records and I'd like to simplify that somehow. Using the temp tables (or materialized views maybe) would simplify that in a way - I'd still need to query 4x for each id but I'd be hitting directly by index to a complete row, which should be much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I definitely wouldn't query the DB 4 times. I would try to query the DB only once, even if it requires nasty and long sql code, in order to reduce round trips between the server and DB.

Just like "Consider Me" and "Gordon Linoff" in the comments I would create a single query with all the fields from all tables and UNION them all. For fields exclusive for some tables I would put 'null' when declaring them in queries for other tables.

For example:

```
select t.description as 'Description', null as 'Value'
from A t
UNION
select null as 'Description', t.value as 'Value'
from B t
```

You can also return ALL fields of all tables and prefix each returned field so you'd know from which table it originated.

For example:

```
select t.description as 'A_Description'
from A t
UNION
select t.value as 'B_Value'
from B t
```

For simplicity, security and efficiency I would put the whole sql code inside a user-defined function that returns a table which you can interpret from the server side code as a recordset. The function would have the ID as a parameter. This can also be achieved in a form of a view.

For efficiency, I would put index on every field that the tables use for join, this should decrease the query time substantially.

In general, I would also try to find out how many times this function is called in a day / hour / minute / sec.
If the data provided by the function is needed frequently, than maybe a whole different approach is needed - rearranging the whole DB. However, if the data is static or semi-static then maybe a caching mechanism is sufficient - in a form of another DB table, server side static object or even a client side static object.

There isn't a simple answer to your question as there are multiple factors to take under consideration.

Comment: Thanks, I'll condense into a single query. My other concern was interleaving the data in the correct way, but I suppose I can do that with an ORDER BY.